# VUE3: Errors after navigating to the homepage (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, runtime-error, vite

I don’t know how to solve this problem.
When I go to the site, this bug pops up:
[image]

After the transition to the main page of the site, such errors occur.
[image: Console Screenshot]
After upgrading the site all is well:
[image]

Always indicates a problem in the file: `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js`
And the 'title' property is null in the `Banner.vue` file.
[image: Banner.vue]
[image: main.js]

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. The error message is quite clear, when you do `const {title, ...etc} = banner`, it fails because the `banner` prop is null. In general, you shouldn't destructure props as the destructured values are not reactive. So you probably want to remove the destructuring and work with props directly, and also check why the prop is not set.

Comment: The file `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js` is just the compiled file which is executed by the browser, there will almost always exists this file when an error is thrown. I am really not sure about your desctructuring syntax on your props.
As well, where do you pass props to this components ? If u don't pass any datas and try to destructure `banner` prop which is null, an error will be thrown